# How to decompose time series seasonality in different components?

Tags: time-series

I have daily sales data which has 3 different seasonality components-
Day of the week
Day of the month
and Week of the year.
How can i find seasonal indexes for each one of them?

Comment: Are you interested in simply getting a result, say using software, or understanding the formula? If the former, consider asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: Post your data and country as each country is treated separately in a csv file and indicate the starting date in order to tease out day-of-the-month , week-of-the month AND the lead and lag effects AROUND each holiday AND possible changes in week-of-the-month or monthly effects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using data formatted as a `tsibble`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(tsibbledata)

daily_elec <- vic_elec %>%
  index_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Demand = sum(Demand))

daily_elec %>%
  model(STL(Demand)) %>%
  components()
#> # A dable:           1,096 x 8 [1D]
#> # Key:               .model [1]
#> # STL Decomposition: Demand = trend + season_year + season_week + remainder
#>    .model Date       Demand  trend season_year season_week remainder
#>    <chr>  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 STL(D… 2012-01-01 2.22e5 2.71e5     -26667.     -20494.    -1158.
#>  2 STL(D… 2012-01-02 2.59e5 2.62e5     -21193.       5507.    11979.
#>  3 STL(D… 2012-01-03 2.67e5 2.54e5      -7617.       3237.    17041.
#>  4 STL(D… 2012-01-04 2.22e5 2.46e5      -7952.      -9226.    -7078.
#>  5 STL(D… 2012-01-05 2.11e5 2.39e5       1153.      -1718.   -27750.
#>  6 STL(D… 2012-01-06 2.10e5 2.31e5     -25564.      20570.   -16173.
#>  7 STL(D… 2012-01-07 2.03e5 2.24e5     -26256.       2318.     2718.
#>  8 STL(D… 2012-01-08 1.93e5 2.22e5      -6154.     -20529.    -2150.
#>  9 STL(D… 2012-01-09 2.14e5 2.20e5      -7003.       5182.    -4400.
#> 10 STL(D… 2012-01-10 2.15e5 2.19e5      -8846.       2817.     1796.
#> # … with 1,086 more rows, and 1 more variable: season_adjust <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Are you sure you have day-of-the-month effects? They would need very careful handling due to the different month lengths, so a periodic seasonal index is not possible. If they are induced by end-of-month events (such as accounting practices), then it is possible to estimate them using a model applied to the remainder term above with a dummy variable indicating the end of each month.